# Get the form ID from a Webform entity

Tags: 8, webforms

I need to output the form id of a webform entity. 
I load a chunk of enabled webforms directly from the database by using

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->loadMultiple();
```

Afterwards I have to output the form_id's of the webform entities.

How to achieve this? I cannot see any "form_id" stored in the returned entity object.

UPDATE:

I can use the following script to receive a static version of the form id:

```
$target_form_id = str_replace('email_confirm_redirect_2_', '', $entity->getSubmissionForm()['#form_id']);
```

Still not really professional

Comment: "contact" is the "webform id". The final form_id should be "webform_submission_contact_add_form".

Of course I can use this a pattern... just prefix  "webform_submission_" and suffix "_add_form". But I thought there would be a cleaner more precise way.

Comment: The webform _entity_ itself doesn't have a unique form ID. The actual form is an entity form for the `webform_submission` entity, and it can have different IDs for different operations (eg. _add_ and _edit_). The logic's in `Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionForm\getFormId()` and it doesn't look like you can cleanly generate the ID without the actual form object, but you can expect the pattern to remain stable for BC with existing form alter hooks. What's the overall goal here?

Comment: I have a backend form that lets users pick an already setup webform. Later then I will react on the form_alter hook to the form id to alter this form. For this scenario I have to save the form id in the database.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than storing the form ID, you could just store the webform ID and check that in a form alter. Webform provides its own form alter hook that only fires for webforms and lets you put the hook in a dedicated include file.

See `honeypot_webform_submission_form_alter()` in [`third_party_settings/webform.honeypot.inc`](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/third_party_settings/webform.honeypot.inc) for an example of getting the webform from the hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_webform_submission_form_alter().
 */
function honeypot_webform_submission_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // <snip>

  /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission */
  $webform_submission = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  $webform = $webform_submission->getWebform();
```

From there you can use `$webform->id()` to get the webform ID.

Comment: I know. But my logic does also react to drupal on core contact forms and custom forms. Maybe I should refactor my module and have a hook for every type which then calls a function. 

Wouldn' the webform id miss the type of view of the form (for example "add")?

Comment: @mogio Webforms can be used both at the admin screen and on a webform node, each with a different form id. Since there's more than one $form_id, you should use the webform ID if you want the webform to be the same in both cases.